# C# Application Exit with Mutex

Tags: c#, mutex

Hope you can help, i have been reading about mutex and I believe I understand it - it should only limit only to one application process.

With some guidance from this community & bit of googling - i have create this simple code.

About the App: Simple Windows Form app in C#

Declared Var :

```
static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "TestAppForm");
```

On AppForm_Load() I have the following code.

```
if (!mutex.WaitOne(2000))
        {

            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();          
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
              // My Code
            }
            finally
            {
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
```

I believe my code works as it's only limiting to only one application.

However, I have noticed that i can see it to flicker when it opens the application and then closes it by mode exit code.

What I would like achieve::

I would like to run the application and check if it's already running - IF not, then great and move on with the rest. 
IF the application is running, I want to end the process & then I want to set FOCUS on the running application.

Thank you.

==

Thanks all your help after some googling I found this post:

http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html

This has helped me to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a singleton application, you cannot implement the `Mutex` logics in `AppForm_Load` because when you reach that point (which is not the entri point / main method of your assembly), it means your application has already been started. With your implementation you can *at best* close the new instance once you notice that another one, previously created, is already running... why not "preventing" the creation of a new instance directly?

This is my template for singleton applications (the `Program` class a the static class that contains my application entry point `static void Main`):

```
#region Using Directives
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#endregion

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class Program
    {
        #region Members: Static
        private static Int32 s_MutexMessage;
        private static Mutex s_Mutex;
        #endregion

        #region Properties: Static
        public static Int32 MutexMessage
        {
            get { return s_MutexMessage; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods: Entry Point
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            String assemblyGuid = ((GuidAttribute)assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0]).Value;
            String mutexName = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Local\\{{{0}}}", assemblyGuid);

            s_MutexMessage = NativeMethods.RegisterWindowMessage(assemblyGuid);

            Boolean mutexCreated;
            s_Mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out mutexCreated);

            if (!mutexCreated)
            {
                NativeMethods.PostMessage((new IntPtr(0xFFFF)), s_MutexMessage, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                return;
            }

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new ApplicationForm());

            s_Mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Then, within the form class (which is `ApplicationForm` in my example):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == Program.MutexMessage)
    {
        if (NativeMethods.IsIconic(Handle))
            NativeMethods.ShowWindow(Handle, 0x00000009);

        NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(Handle);
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Finally, for the sake of completeness, here are the importations that my code use, located within the `NativeMethods` class (remember to mark it as `internal`, it's a good practice that should not be neglected):

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    #region Importations
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern Boolean IsIconic([In] IntPtr windowHandle);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = false, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern Boolean PostMessage([In, Optional] IntPtr windowHandle, [In] Int32 message, [In] IntPtr wParameter, [In] IntPtr lParameter);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern Boolean SetForegroundWindow([In] IntPtr windowHandle);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern Boolean ShowWindow([In] IntPtr windowHandle, [In] Int32 command);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = false, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern Int32 RegisterWindowMessage([In] String message);
}
```

This implementation is a little bit longer than the traditional one based only on a `Mutex` object, needs a wide usage of native interop and must be splitted among different classes within your project... but I use it template since long long time ago and I can affirm that it's bulletproof.

Comment: Thank you Tommaso, I will look at it now - Must admit, this NativeMethods are advanced for me at this point [new to c#]

Comment: Altrough advances, it's just a matter of copy-pasting here. And of course you will learn something in the meanwhile xD

Comment: Sorry :( - i'm getting error for ""string mutexname = ("Local\\{{{0}}}").FormatInvariant(assemblyGuid); 
I'm not sure where I paste the protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {} I pasted in within the Form1() but that also reported error.
I created new form to test it - thank you.

Comment: I used to use Mutex code very similar to this that I wrote myself. But occasionally on a multi-threaded, multi-process with IPC application I wrote, we found that the mutex was being created despite already being in use.  I ended up falling back to the old exclusive file write of a temporary unqiuely named file that no other app should ever use.  Your results may vary and I was always under the impression that should never happen.

Comment: @netniV I think that's because the Mutex must either be created with "Global" or "Local" prefix depending on its usage and the environment in which the application is being run. Read here for more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Azmodan sorry that FormatInvariant thing was a leftover of my code... I fixed it, in my answer. The WndProc method should be included in your form class, you are right. What error is it throwing?

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo - when I paste it bellow InitiliazeCom...(); - I get expected "}" - then "IF (m.msg == Program.MutexMessage) = Program doesn't contain definition of MutexMessage
I take it put in wrong place. Thank you

Comment: Have you changed this "namespace MyNamespace" with your current and correct assembly namespace? Have you set Program.Main as the entry point in the project properties? Also, doublecheck that there are no syntax errors and be patient :)

Comment: I changed the namespace in the properties - and i can't find the 2nd part as what you mean. I have to go now, so I will have to come back to it tomorrow. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

AppForm_Load isn't the first entry point of your application. Find the code that creates the form and do it there instead.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, can I assume that you mean AppForm() it has InitializeComponent(); inside?

Comment: Unless you've changed the boilerplate code VS generates for you, the entry point isn't in AppForm at all. As I said, find the code that *creates* the form.

Answer (score 0):

Do not check the mutex in your `AppForm_Load`, instead check it in the `Main` method like this:

```
private static Mutex _mutex = new Mutex(true, "AppMutex");

static void Main()
{
    if(!_mutex.WaitOne(0, true))
    {
        return;
    }

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new AppForm());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An object is defined as a data in this method we can update more than one variables in single array with constant data type in the CSharp Programming in class as assigned to this application in an mutux class this is how come but reliable and predictable